# Create Oracle View with columns from row

Tags: oracle, join

these are my two tables:

table1:

```
ID   |   Description
0    |   test
1    |   test1
```

table2:

```
ID   |   YEAR   | VALUE
0    |  2019    | 1000
0    |  2020    | 2000
1    |  2019    | 3000
1    |  2020    | 4000
```

I would like to have this view (2019 and 2020 could be custom rows):

```
ID   | Description   | 2019   | 2020
0    | test          | 1000   | 2000
1    | test1         | 3000   | 4000
```

I know how to join those two tables but not how to add the values from table2 to that custom column. Thanks

Comment: you can use either pivot or MAX function in Oracle to convert row to columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join combined with aggregation/pivoting:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.YEAR = 2019 THEN t2.VALUE END) AS "2019",
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.YEAR = 2020 THEN t2.VALUE END) AS "2020"
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.Description
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

[image: screen capture of demo query]

### Demo

Comment: in FROM clause it should be table1 t1

Answer (score 1):

Use below `View`:

```
Create View View_name 
as 
SELECT
    tbl1.ID,
    tbl1.Description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.YEAR = 2019 THEN tbl2.VALUE END) AS "2019",
    MAX(CASE WHEN tbl2.YEAR = 2020 THEN tbl2.VALUE END) AS "2020"
FROM table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2
    ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
GROUP BY
    tbl1.ID,
    tbl1.Description;
```